# Como pular para o próximo valor do array bidimensional e printar esse valor

Tags: javascript, array

Gostaria de pegar o valor do segundo índice do array " jogo[0][1]=["1", "15/06", "09:00", "Egito",  tenho de pular para o próximo jogo (próxima linha) até achar um jogo que bata com a condição do meu if...

```
var atualizacao="10/05/2018 17:03:55";

var rodadaAtual = 1;

var jogo = new Array(7);
jogo[0] = new Array();
jogo[1] = new Array();
jogo[2] = new Array();
jogo[3] = new Array();
jogo[4] = new Array();
jogo[5] = new Array();
jogo[6] = new Array();

//rodada, data, hora, time 1, placar 1, time 2, placar 2

jogo[0][0]=["1", "14/05", "08:00", "Russia", "", "Arabia Saudita", "0"];
jogo[0][1]=["1", "15/06", "09:00", "Egito", "", "Uruguai", ""];
jogo[0][2]=["1", "15/06", "8:00", "Marrocos", "", "Ir�", ""];
jogo[0][3]=["1", "15/06", "15:00", "Portugal", "", "Espanha", ""];
jogo[0][4]=["1", "16/06", "07:00", "Fran�a", "", "Austr�lia", ""];
jogo[0][5]=["1", "16/06", "10:00", "Argentina", "", "Isl�ndia", ""];
jogo[0][6]=["1", "16/06", "13:00", "Peru", "", "Dinamarca", ""];
jogo[0][7]=["1", "16/06", "16:00", "Cro�cia", "", "Nig�ria", ""];
jogo[0][8]=["1", "17/06", "09:00", "Costa Rica", "", "S�rvia", ""];
jogo[0][9]=["1", "17/06", "12:00", "Alemanha", "", "M�xico", ""];
jogo[0][10]=["1", "17/06", "15:00", "Brasil", "", "Su��a", ""];
jogo[0][11]=["1", "18/06", "09:00", "Su�cia", "", "Coreia do Sul", ""];
jogo[0][12]=["1", "18/06", "12:00", "Tun�sia", "", "Inglaterra", ""];
jogo[0][13]=["1", "18/06", "15:00", "B�lgica", "", "Panam�", ""];
jogo[0][14]=["1", "19/06", "09:00", "Col�mbia", "", "Jap�o", ""];
jogo[0][15]=["1", "19/06", "12:00", "Pol�nia", "", "Senegal", ""];

jogo[1][0]=["2", "19/06", "15:00", "R�ssia", "", "Egito", ""];
jogo[1][1]=["2", "20/06", "09:00", "Portugal", "", "Marrocos", ""];
jogo[1][2]=["2", "20/06", "12:00", "Uruguai", "", "Ar�bia Saudita", ""];
jogo[1][3]=["2", "20/06", "15:00", "Ir�", "", "Espanha", ""];
jogo[1][4]=["2", "21/06", "09:00", "Dinamarca", "", "Austr�lia", ""];
jogo[1][5]=["2", "21/06", "12:00", "Fran�a", "", "Peru", ""];
jogo[1][6]=["2", "21/06", "15:00", "Argentina", "", "Cro�cia", ""];
jogo[1][7]=["2", "22/06", "09:00", "Brasil", "", "Costa Rica", ""];
jogo[1][8]=["2", "22/06", "12:00", "Nig�ria", "", "Isl�ndia", ""];
jogo[1][9]=["2", "22/06", "15:00", "S�rvia", "", "Su��a", ""];
jogo[1][10]=["2", "23/06", "09:00", "B�lgica", "", "Tun�sia", ""];
jogo[1][11]=["2", "23/06", "12:00", "Coreia do Sul", "", "M�xico", ""];
jogo[1][12]=["2", "23/06", "15:00", "Alemanha", "", "Su�cia", ""];
jogo[1][13]=["2", "24/06", "09:00", "Inglaterra", "", "Panam�", ""];
jogo[1][14]=["2", "24/06", "12:00", "Jap�o", "", "Senegal", ""];
jogo[1][15]=["2", "24/06", "15:00", "Pol�nia", "", "Col�mbia", ""];

jogo[2][0]=["3", "25/06", "11:00", "Uruguai", "", "R�ssia", ""];
jogo[2][1]=["3", "25/06", "11:00", "Ar�bia Saudita", "", "Egito", ""];
jogo[2][2]=["3", "25/06", "15:00", "Espanha", "", "Marrocos", ""];
jogo[2][3]=["3", "25/06", "15:00", "Ir�", "", "Portugal", ""];
jogo[2][4]=["3", "26/06", "11:00", "Dinamarca", "", "Fran�a", ""];
jogo[2][5]=["3", "26/06", "11:00", "Austr�lia", "", "Peru", ""];
jogo[2][6]=["3", "26/06", "15:00", "Nig�ria", "", "Argentina", ""];
jogo[2][7]=["3", "26/06", "15:00", "Isl�ndia", "", "Cro�cia", ""];
jogo[2][8]=["3", "27/06", "11:00", "M�xico", "", "Su�cia", ""];
jogo[2][9]=["3", "27/06", "11:00", "Coreia do Sul", "", "Alemanha", ""];
jogo[2][10]=["3", "27/06", "15:00", "S�rvia", "", "Brasil", ""];
jogo[2][11]=["3", "27/06", "15:00", "Su��a", "", "Costa Rica", ""];
jogo[2][12]=["3", "28/06", "11:00", "Jap�o", "", "Pol�nia", ""];
jogo[2][13]=["3", "28/06", "11:00", "Senegal", "", "Col�mbia", ""];
jogo[2][14]=["3", "28/06", "15:00", "Panam�", "", "Tun�sia", ""];
jogo[2][15]=["3", "28/06", "15:00", "Inglaterra", "", "B�lgica", ""];

jogo[3][0]=["4", "30/06", "11:00", "1� do grupo C", "", "2� do grupo D", ""];
jogo[3][1]=["4", "30/06", "15:00", "1� do grupo A", "", "2� do grupo B", ""];
jogo[3][2]=["4", "01/07", "11:00", "1� do grupo B", "", "2� do grupo A", ""];
jogo[3][3]=["4", "01/07", "15:00", "1� do grupo D", "", "2� do grupo C", ""];
jogo[3][4]=["4", "02/07", "11:00", "1� do grupo E", "", "2� do grupo F", ""];
jogo[3][5]=["4", "02/07", "15:00", "1� do grupo G", "", "2� do grupo H", ""];
jogo[3][6]=["4", "03/07", "11:00", "1� do grupo F", "", "2� do grupo E", ""];
jogo[3][7]=["4", "03/07", "15:00", "1� do grupo H", "", "2� do grupo G", ""];

jogo[4][0]=["5", "06/07", "11:00", "Vencedor Oitavas 1", "", "Vencedor Oitavas 2", ""];
jogo[4][1]=["5", "06/07", "15:00", "Vencedor Oitavas 3", "", "Vencedor Oitavas 4", ""];
jogo[4][2]=["5", "07/07", "11:00", "Vencedor Oitavas 7", "", "Vencedor Oitavas 8", ""];
jogo[4][3]=["5", "07/07", "15:00", "Vencedor Oitavas 5", "", "Vencedor Oitavas 6", ""];

jogo[5][0]=["6", "10/07", "15:00", "Vencedor Quartas 1", "", "Vencedor Quartas 2", ""];
jogo[5][1]=["6", "11/07", "15:00", "Vencedor Quartas 3", "", "Vencedor Quartas 4", ""];

jogo[6][0]=["7", "14/07", "11:00", "Perdedor Semifinal 1", "", "Perdedor Semifinal 2", ""];
jogo[6][1]=["7", "15/07", "12:00", "Vencedor Semifinal 1", "", "Vencedor Semifinal 2", ""];







function verificarJogo(){                   
            for (i = 0; i < jogo.length; i++) {
                alert("---------------- HORARIO JOGO   "+horaDoJogo,0);
                alert("---------------- DATA DO JOGO  "+dataJogoAtual,0);
                alert("---------------- HORARIO DO SISTEMA  "+hora,0);
                alert("---------------- DATA DO SISTEMA  "+today,0);
                alert("----------------rodadaAtual  "+rodadaAtual,0);   
                alert("----------- primeiro for "+i,0);

                for (j = 0; j < linhas && aux < jogo[rodadaAtual - 1].length; j++) {                        
                    if(today == dataJogoAtual && hora == horaDoJogo){                           
                        alert("----------- entrou no if "+i,0);
                        eval("document.myForm2.strData" + i + ".value='"+ jogo[rodadaAtual - 1][aux][1] + "';");
                        eval("document.myForm2.strHora" + i + ".value='"+ jogo[rodadaAtual - 1][aux][2] + "';");
                        eval("document.myForm2.strTime1_" + i + ".value='"+ jogo[rodadaAtual - 1][aux][3] + "';");
                        eval("document.myForm2.strRes1_" + i + ".value='"+ jogo[rodadaAtual - 1][aux][4] + "';");
                        eval("document.myForm2.separador" + i + ".value='X';");
                        eval("document.myForm2.strRes2_" + i + ".value='"+ jogo[rodadaAtual - 1][aux][6] + "';");
                        eval("document.myForm2.strTime2_" + i + ".value='"+ jogo[rodadaAtual - 1][aux][5] + "';");                          
                        break;

                    }
                    aux++;                      
                }


            }                       

    }
```

Comment: Não utilize `eval` para o que está a tentar fazer, pois é desnecessário. Quanto à questão em si ficou meio vaga. Quer pular para o próximo jogo quando ? Quais são os que quer mostrar ? Tem como mostrar um exemplo do que esperaria ver depois desse codigo executar ?

Comment: Olá Isac , eu gostaria de fazer uma função que verificasse dentro desse array qual jogo é compatível com a data do meu sistema e a hora .porque do jeito que eu fiz , só pega a primeira linha sempre e não está entrando nessa condicao do If

Comment: O que entende por compatível ?

Comment: Compatível seria entrar no IF para printar o valor certo ... Estou aprendendo agora a programar , desculpe

Comment: O que significa para si um "jogo ser compatível com a data do sistema e a hora" ? Pode dar exemplos de jogos que considera compatíveis ? Seriam jogos que tenham o mesmo dia e a mesma hora, ignorando mes, ano ? ou mês e ano também seriam considerados ?

Comment: Por exemplo Isac , hoje é dia 15/05 e são 09:00 no meu array tem esse valor na segunda posição Egito vs Uruguai.  .  Gostaria de printar ele na tela

Comment: Mas a sua hora de sistema é `var atualizacao="10/05/2018 17:03:55";` ou seja 17:03, e como é que ele imprime o jogo do Uruguai se esse tem hora `09:00`. Ainda não consegui perceber o critério exato que você quer utilizar para mostrar os jogos

Comment: Essa var atualização é quando o arquivo foi gerado ,não estou usando ela para nada  mas se vc observar os jogos tem todos suas próprias datas e horários , para pegar o horário do meu sistema( do meu PC. )  eu estou dando um getHours() e um getDate() e guardando isso em uma variável para comparar com os valores de data e hora do jogo .